# Spark-SQL > access hive tables with Serde: Exception in task in stage java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I am using `Spark-SQL` to access `Hive` tables through `Spark-shell`. As the data in Hive table is stored in special compressed format, SerDe jar is needed to read the data.

I have the following scala code in Spark-shell:

```
Scala > sqlContext.sql("ADD JAR /../SerDe.jar")
Scala > sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE ... InputFormat ...OutputFormat")
Scala > sqlContext.sql("LOAD DATA ... INTO TABLE ...")
```

Until here everything went fine, i.e. data was successfully loaded into the `Hive` table in `HDFS`.

But then I continue to access data in the Hive table:

```
 Scala > sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from ...").collect().foreach(println)
```

Then there are errors:

> ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor: Exception in task in stage
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data

I am pretty new in Spark-sql, so it is really my pleasure to get some hints from here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are these steps working fine on the hiveCLI? Spark is not executing anything until you are hitting the println. So the error can be anywhere.

Comment: of course with hiveCLI it worked fine! in the code you can see "println", but it definitely did arrive in that step yet

Comment: I am not being able to reproduce the issue with my configuration. But I have found a reported issues on apache-spark Jira (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1867). The reason can be the wrong -Dhadoop.version while you were building spark. check your Hadoop version ($hadoop version) and use the right version while building Spark (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html). For me, it was "2.5.0-cdh5.3.3".  Apart from that you should always check if the hive-site.xml is in your spark conf folder and external jar (e.g. the SerDe jar ) is on your spark classpath.

Comment: About hive-site.xml, according to my understanding we can ignore it, as a result, the metastore and derby.log is generated in the current directory. Plz comment if I get some misunderstanding.

I included the external jar with the option --jars of spark-shell, I guess this is OK, right?

Comment: About hive-site.xml, according to my understanding we can ignore it, as a result, the metastore and derby.log is generated in the current directory. Plz comment if I get some misunderstanding.

I included the external jar with the option --jars of spark-shell, I guess this is OK, right?

the "create table ..." included the Serde, InputFormat, and OutputFormat, and it went fine, so it seems that Spark-Shell indeed recognized the jar I gave

Comment: Ok. But as highlighted in my previous comment the prime suspect for your problem is the spark build for wrong Hadoop version. Can you please share information on how you built the spark and what is the output when you run #hadoop version on your system. I am running my hive metastore on MySQL so I can't exactly comment on your situation there.

Comment: Please also mention which Java  & Spark versions you are using.